# Parse a Json String to create a new custom object c#

Tags: c#, json

I am returning a json string to a WebMethod in WebForms and I want to take the json string and parse it into custom `Order` objects.

I have a class:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
}
```

And a WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SendOrder(string json)
{
    List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();

    return json;
}
```

I am passing this string:

```
{
    json: [
        {
            "Item":"Nike Polo #286772 - Women's Dri-FIT Micro Pique Short Sleeved Polo",
            "Size":"XL",
            "Color":"Light Blue",
            "Quantity":"3"
        },
        {
            "Item":"Port Authority Women's Jacket #L790 - Black",
            "Size":"Medium",
            "Color":"Black",
            "Quantity":"3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to loop through this string and creating new Orders.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'd use JSON.Net. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Okay, I have added that reference and I am working on parsing the string into the objects.

Comment: This is how i would parse the json right:  var orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(json);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That JSON is a little oddly formatted as it maps to the following classes (using http://json2csharp.com):

```
public class Json
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Json> json { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure why you have a top-level variable named `json`, but whatever.

At this point just use JSON.NET to deserialize into the structure.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJsonString);
```

If you want to rename the object from `Json` to `Order` you'll need to use an attribute for that. I don't recall the name off the top of my head but it should be easy to find in the JSON.NET documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I recently completed a Windows Phone app that retrieved info from a Web API-based server as Json strings.  I ended up using the [JsonConvert](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) class to convert my lists of objects from Json strings to my custom objects.  Here's an example of one of my client-side methods that receives and converts the Json strings:

```
public async void GetGames()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("base url");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("specific url extention (like api/Order)");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(s);
//rest of code


            }
        }
    }
```

Also, make sure that your web method is actually doing something.  The example web method you posted creates creates a new list then just returns the parameter you passed in.  Using Web API, you could return a list of all Order objects in your database via a method similar to the following:

```
public IQueryable<Order> GetOrders()
    {
        return db.Orders; //db is an instance of your DbContext class
    }
```

I hope this is helpful.  Let me know if you have any questions.